# Finding Max/Min number in list in Ocaml

Tags: recursion, compiler-errors, ocaml

I just began to learn Ocaml recently and now just started to practice some codes.
In this case, I tried to find a maximum number in a list but it keeps return me an error message.

```
let max: int list -> int
= fun lst ->
match lst with
 |[] -> 0
 |h::[] -> h
 |h::t -> let a = max t in
            if h < a then h
            else
             a;;
```

Ocaml keeps saying:

> Error: This expression has type int list -> int list but an expression was expected of type int.

I don't understand why a is an int list though I claimed it as a max t which is a function that makes int list into int... Thanks for yout help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` has type `int list -> int list` because `max` in `let a = max t` does not refer to your function, but to [the one defined in `Stdlib`](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Stdlib.html#VALmax). `Stdlib` (Previously called `Pervasives`) contains definitions used very commonly and is therefore opened for you by default.

`Stdlib.max` has the type `'a -> 'a -> 'a`. So when you pass it an `int list`, the compiler infers `'a` to be `int list` and returns a function with type `int list -> int list`.

Why does `max` not refer to your own `max` function? Because you've forgotten the `rec` keyword. As you probably know already, `rec` makes the function available to be called inside itself.

You should avoid shadowing `Stdlib` function names to avoid confusing errors like this. If you had chosen a different name, you'd simply get an error telling you that `max` does not exist.